# Replace numbered paragraphs from one document to another?

Tags: script, regex, find-and-replace

I have two documents that are identical, but one is in English, the other in Spanish.  I took the first and took care of reformatting it by hand, mostly.  Now, rather than going through the lengthy reformatting process again with the Spanish document, I'd like to merely substitute each paragraph from the Spanish language document into the English language document.

Is there a way to do this, like "copy and paste format" from the English document to the Spanish one, or substitute the text without moving the old format from the Spanish one to the English one?  I've considered using RegEx, but cannot fathom a solution with that, and running hundreds of Find-And-Replace queries is no good.

The old file is html, and the new file is markdown.  (I do know about html to markdown converters, but the html is poorly done.)  I'm using various Markdown editors.

Comment: 1) What is the format of the document and what software are you using to create/edit it?  2) Asking for a program as a solution makes the question off-topic.  Instead, just ask how to solve the problem.  There may be a solution that doesn't require additional software, and people are free to suggest a software solution if one is needed.

Comment: I'm using various Markdown editors.

Comment: I added some "alternative" solutions (second paragraph) to get people's thought process going, thinking you were using a word processor.  Feel free to remove this if it isn't relevant.